# how to simplify a line using JTS?

Tags: java, geometry, line, coordinates, jts

I have a `List<Coordinate>` which represents a route.

I want to simplify it using JTS.

I saw few method but I wasn't sure which one will fit my needs the best:

1) how can I convert my coordinate to geometry (line?)

```
TopologyPreservingSimplifier(Geometry inputGeom) 

void    setDistanceTolerance(double distanceTolerance) 

Geometry    getResultGeometry()
```

2)

```
DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier(Coordinate[] pts) 

 void   setDistanceTolerance(double distanceTolerance) 

 Coordinate[]   simplify() 

static Coordinate[] simplify(Coordinate[] pts, double distanceTolerance)
```

3) maybe this?

`TopologyPreservingSimplifier.simplify(geom, threshold-in-degrees-that-depends-on-the-length);`

Answer (score 1):

To simplify a line you first have to have one. So first build your LineString using the `createLineString(Coordinate[])` method of a GeometryFactory instance.

Then just use the DouglasPeuckerSimplifier (you don't need to preserve topology for just one line, the start and end points are all the topology there and they won't be changed). You will have to cast the result to a LineString again if you want to use it as such later on. And you will have to choose an appropriate tolerance.

```
LineString lss = (LineString) DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(ls, tolerance);
```